# Really with [socket.join(the_other_room);] the client join to other room?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Regards, previusly I create the rom "/other_room" with:

```
io.of('/other_room');
```

then after I do:

```
socket.on('MessageFromClient_Change_Of_ROOM', function(msj){

// yes!, I validate var msj == '/other_room'


console.log('before: ' + socket.nsp['name']);
socket.join(msj);
console.log('after: ' + socket.nsp['name']);
}
```

but FOREVER my console print:

```
before: /
after: /
```

why this socket NEVER change to "/other_room" ???

Thanks

EDITION/ADDITION:

This is my "code:

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(6969);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        clientes ++;
        server.sockets.emit('eventCONEX', clientes);
        // here my lines of code with "events" ...
        // then ALL "new connection" by default go into '/'...
        // then all "new connection" have assigned the namespace "/"
     });
```

please: how I transport/move users from "this default [/]" to "personalized"??

I have a gurp of clients: A, B, C, E, ..., Z

Then ever when I use:

```
        io.sockets.emit('My Event', the_info);
```

the window browser in remote client, show "the_info" to ALL clients connecteds to "/" or socket/room/namespace by default.

I need users can create "Room_created_by_A" or "Room_created_by_B"...

I believed the instruction:

```
socket.join(new_name);
```

were the method correct, but now I understand no is the correct.

Then when client send the message "create_new_room", I run the lines:

```
function list_of_rooms(){
    s = '';
    for(S in server.nsps)s += S + '\n';
    return s;
}

server.of(msj);
server.of(socket.nsp['name']).emit('F5_rooms', list_of_rooms());
```

I try explain newly:

When client A create "room" [thecnology] then my code/program run update of "list_of_rooms()" then some clients as F, G, H can GO TO room [thecnology].

Then becouse group {A, F, G, H} is into room [thecnology], if they send a message ONLY the group {A, F, G, H} recived the message, becouse the message or "multicast" is only to clients into [thecnology].

I believe this message/multicast is possible with:

```
server.of(socket.nsp['name']).emit('new_message_to_this_group', message);
```

newly, thanks by help; (I believe perhaps no is authorized say thanks)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  `io.of('/other_room');` does NOT create a room.  That gets you a namespace object that would allow you to communicate with any connections that connected to that particular namespace.  Absolutely nothing to do with rooms.  You seem to be confusing rooms and namespaces.  They are different things.

Comment: Thanks by your help. When I run:

  for(S in server.nsps)console.log(S)

I see the "name of each room" and just I see room '/' and others...
just as say https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ (We call the default namespace / and ...)
surely I am mistake, then please any help is very welcome...

Oh!, then socket.join(msj); create OTHER NAMESPACE, no other room??

Comment: You will have to explain what you are trying to accomplish in words and then I could probably show you the right code for that.  But you need to clearly describe what you are trying to accomplish and edit your question to say that.

Comment: Thanks very much by your patience. I believe know {socket.id} is the id of each client...

Then if I have 10 clients connecteds, and [room] by default is "/" (https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) I like some client create other [room] with name different to "/" and then any {socket.id} GO TO "new_room" then if any client send a message to "new_room" ONLY the {socket.id}s connecteds to "new_room" recibe the message sended to "new_room". ( I believe the message is sended with io.of(socket.nsp['name']).emit('event', msj); Thanks newly.

Comment: You have both downvotes and close votes.  Please FIX  your question as I've advised you several times to avoid getting more downvotes and to avoid having your question closed.  Your question as it is written now is NOT clear and it needs to be fixed to be clear.  That's how stack overflow works.  Only good, clear, on-topic questions are allowed here.  If you get feedback that your question is not clear, you need to fix it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You have completely confused namespaces with rooms.  They are two completely different things and to use rooms, you don't need to do anything with namespaces.  To put a client socket into a room, you do this on your server with that particular client's socket:

```
socket.join("someRoom");
```

Then, to send a message to everyone in that room from the server, you do this:

```
io.in("someRoom").emit("msg", "Hello to all");
```

If you wanted to use your `MessageFromClient_Change_Of_ROOM` message to join a room, you could do this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('MessageFromClient_Change_Of_ROOM', function(msj){
        // assumes client is only supposed to be in one room
        // and keeps track of prior room in socket.priorRoom
        if (socket.priorRoom) {
           // leave previous room
           socket.leave(socket.priorRoom);
        }
        // join new room
        socket.join(msj);
        socket.priorRoom = msj;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is my "code: 
  `var io = require('socket.io').listen(6969);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   clientes ++;
   io.sockets.emit('eventCONEX', clientes);
   // here my lines of code with "events" ...
   // then ALL "new connection" by default go into '/'...
   // then all "new connection" have assigned the namespace "/"
   `
please: how I transport/move the users from default to "personalized" ??

Comment: @VyR - Multiline code is not readable in comments.  Use the "edit" button to add it to your question and then post a comment to tell people that you edited your question.  Also, please use the edit button to put the description of what you're trying to do into your question too.  Questions here need to be clear for everyone to understand.  Poor questions are downvoted or closed - that's part of what makes this a higher quality Q&A site than many on the internet because the members police the quality of questions and answers.  You need to follow the proper procedures here.